# Is there any reason why not to use actions to get data from a flux store?

Tags: angularjs, store, flux

My understanding of how a view and a store interact in flux has been evolving. There seems to me to be three patterns.

The code here is written as if for angular-flux, but I think the ideas apply generally to flux.

**Pattern 1 - store getter is synchronous**

```
// Get my data from the store
data = store.get();
// If store has data then do stuff with it
if (data !== undefined) {
    handleUpdate(data);
} else { // load the data from the server
    actionCreator.getData();
}
scope.$listenTo(store, "UPDATE", function (data) {
    // Listen to updates to the data
    handleUpdate(data);
})
```

**Pattern 2 - store getter is async**

```
// store will call the server and get the data for you if it doesn't have it
store.get().promise().then(handleUpdate(data));
scope.$listenTo(store, "UPDATE", function (data) {
    // Listen to updates to the data
    handleUpdate(data);
})
```

**Pattern 3 - use actions and events to get the data from the store, so the async handling only happens in one place**

```
scope.$listenTo(store, "UPDATE", function (data) {
    // Listen to updates to the data
    handleUpdate(data);
})
flux.dispatch("GET")
```

In pattern 3, the store would look something like this:

```
store.handler["GET"] = function () {
    if (this.state.data) {
        this.emit("GET", this.state.data);    
    } else {
        dataResource.get().$promise.then(function(data) {
            flux.dispatch("UPDATE", data);
        });
    }
}

store.handler["UPDATE"] = function (data) {
    this.state.set("data", data);
    this.emit("GET", this.state.data);
}
```

I like pattern 3 because

- It keeps the complexity of getting data from the server in the store
  (at least not duplicated everywhere that uses the store)
- The component only has to handle the asynchronous event in one place

The trouble is it breaks the idea that stores only emit events when they change, in this case it might emit an event when it hasn't changed, just so the component which asked for the data can receive it via the event listening system.

Is their anything fundamentally broken about doing this which will catch me out later? Because it doesn't follow the pure flux approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do something similar to pattern 3. The entry app calls an action to initialize the api and call the initial data. Api actions for getting data are handled by an api.store. The api.store is the only object that calls the api for requests. The api calls other actions on receipt of data. These calls are handled by the relevant store.

app.js

```js
'use strict';

import React  from 'react';
import ReactDom  from 'react-dom';

import AppCtrl from './components/app.ctrl.js';
import Actions from './actions/api.Actions';
import ApiStore from './stores/Api.Store';

window.ReactDom = ReactDom;

Actions.apiInit();

ReactDom.render( <AppCtrl />, document.getElementById('react') );
```

api.store.js

```js
import Reflux from 'reflux';

import Actions from '../actions/api.Actions';
import ApiFct from '../utils/sa.api';

let ApiStoreObject = {
  newData: {
    "React version": "0.14",
    "Project": "ReFluxSuperAgent",
    "currentDateTime": new Date().toLocaleString()
  },
  listenables: Actions,
  apiInit() { ApiFct.setData(this.newData); },
  apiInitDone() { ApiFct.getData(); },
  apiSetData(data) { ApiFct.setData(data); }
}
const ApiStore = Reflux.createStore(ApiStoreObject);
export default ApiStore;
```

sa.api.js

```js
import request from 'superagent';

import apiActions from '../actions/api.Actions';
import saActions from '../actions/sa.Actions';

module.exports = {
  getData() { request.get('/routes/getData').end((err, res) => { this.gotData(res.body); }); },
  gotData(data) { saActions.gotData1(data); saActions.gotData2(data); saActions.gotData3(data); },
  setData(data) { request.post('/routes/setData').send(data).end((err, res) => { apiActions.apiInitDone(); }) },
};
```

basic.store.js

```js
import Reflux from 'reflux';

import Actions from '../actions/sa.Actions';
import AddonStore from './Addon.Store';
import MixinStoreObject from './Mixin.Store';

function _GotData(data) { this.data1 = data; BasicStore.trigger('data1'); }

let BasicStoreObject = {
  init() { this.listenTo(AddonStore, this.onAddonTrigger); },
  data1: {},
  listenables: Actions,
  mixins: [MixinStoreObject],
  onGotData1: _GotData,
  onAddonTrigger() { BasicStore.trigger('data2'); },
  getData1() { return this.data1; },
  getData2() { return AddonStore.data2; },
  getData3() { return this.data3; }
}
const BasicStore = Reflux.createStore(BasicStoreObject);
export default BasicStore;
```